# Php getting error condition is not working correctly

Tags: php, zip

Hi I'm trying to create a zip and adding some pdf files into it but getting error when i try to check if the folder exists or not i don't know where I'm doing mistake please tell me if my code is right or wrong .
Here is my code .

```
public function createZips(){

    if (is_dir("/home/servername/public_html/wp-content/pdf_files/".$stdname)){

        if(!(file_exists("/home/servername/public_html/wp-content/pdf_files/".$stdname."/zip/".$ct[-1].".zip"))){
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $filename = "/home/servername/public_html/wp-content/pdf_files/".$stdname."/zip/".$ct[-1].".zip";

            if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
                exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
            }

            $dir = "/home/servername/public_html/wp-content/pdf_files/".$stdname."/".$ct[-1];

            // Create zip
            $this->createZip($zip,$dir);

            $zip->close();
        }
        return ture;
    }
    return false;
}

// Create zip
public function createZip($zip,$dir){
    if (is_dir($dir)){

        if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

                // If file
                if (is_file($dir.$file)) {
                    if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){

                        $zip->addFile($dir.$file);
                    }
                }else{
                    // If directory
                    if(is_dir($dir.$file) ){

                        if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){

                            // Add empty directory
                            $zip->addEmptyDir($dir.$file);

                            $folder = $dir.$file.'/';

                            // Read data of the folder
                            $this->createZip($zip,$folder);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
}
```

Please have a look at this i think this is a simple condition check but i don't know where i'm mistaken 
My question is not duplicate cause i'm getting an error message that says file is not in the folder here is the error 
Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No such file or directory in /home/ameliadeol2015/public_html/wp-content/plugins/lifterlms/includes/admin/reporting/tables/llms.table.student.courses.php on line 137

Comment: Check your error log. I bet there is something about `$ct` not defined

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I'm defining $ct which is taking a string value which i'm using the problem is that i'm getting error that file does not exist while the folder and file is there if (is_dir("/home/servername/public_html/wp-content/pdf_files/".$stdname)) the problem is in this line i'm checking if the folder exist or not . but this is nor working correct how

Comment: I don't see how $ct is available within the scope of your createZips() function. It is not defined within the function, it is not passed to the function and is not a global variable.

Comment: Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No such file or directory in /home/ameliadeol2015/public_html/wp-content/plugins/lifterlms/includes/admin/reporting/tables/llms.table.student.courses.php on line 137 –

Comment: @Mr-Glass sir $ct is a class variable  which i'm using in

Comment: @HuzailJamil, if it is a class variable then you should be using $this->ct to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be defining $ct, so when you try to access $ct[-1] it's not going to have a value.

Comment: Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No such file or directory in /home/ameliadeol2015/public_html/wp-content/plugins/lifterlms/includes/admin/reporting/tables/llms.table.student.courses.php on line 137

Comment: I'm defining $ct which is taking a string value which i'm using the problem is that i'm getting error that file does not exist while the folder and file is there if (is_dir("/home/servername/public_html/wp-content/pdf_files/".$stdname)) the problem is in this line i'm checking if the folder exist or not . but this is nor working correct how

Comment: Who voted this down? It is the correct answer. $ct is not defined. It turns out he should be using $this->ct.

Comment: i don't know who turned this down